# Angular 2 firebase can't get image from database

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have uploaded img URL to my database with that functon :

```
  private saveFileData(upload: Upload): void {
    this.firebaseAuth.authState.subscribe(auth => {
    this.db.list(`uploads/${auth && auth.email && auth.uid}`).push(upload);
    })
  }
```

After that I want to get it with that function, first one is the **pathreference**, since I only want that **logged in users will see what they are uploading by themselfs** :

```
this.firebaseAuth.authState.subscribe(auth => {
  if(auth && auth.email && auth.uid) {
this.uploadRef = this.db.list<any>(`uploads/${auth && auth.email && auth.uid}`);
    console.log("Gaunami profilio duomenys")
  }
  else {
    console.log("Nerandama img")
  }

})
```

And at last I want to get list of **uploaded images like that**  :

```
get getListUploads(): Observable<AngularFireAction<DatabaseSnapshot>[]> {
    return this.uploadRef.snapshotChanges().map(changes => {
      return changes.map(c => ({ key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() }));
    });
  }
```

**I get error in console :**

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'snapshotChanges' of undefined
    at UploadService.get [as getListUploads] (upload.service.ts:30)
```

**Upload works fine, i see photo name and url in my DB, I see photo in storage, but can't get it from there. Any advices ?**

Comment: where your getListUploads getter is used? Could you add the upload.service.ts to your question ?

Answer (score 1):

Your reference to the file is incorrect. You're using conditions to save it :

```
auth && auth.email && auth.uid
```

Look at what it returns when you us that in JS :

```js
console.log({auth: true} && 'foo.bar@gmail.com' && 207894193784);
```

this means that when you save your post, only the ID is used in its name.

Now let's test without one of the criterias of the condition being fullfilled :

```js
console.log({auth: true} && '' && 207894193784);
```

As you can see, if the mail isn't provided, you don't get any name.

You must rewrite your reference to the file, this should resolve your issue itself.

**EDIT** as proposed, an example of a service

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireStorage } from 'angularfire2/storage';

@Injectable()
export class StorageService {

  constructor(
    private afsStorage: AngularFireStorage
  ) { }

  createFile(file: File, folder = 'unclassified'): Observable<string> {
    const path = `${Date.now()}-${Math.random().toString(36).slice(-8)}.${file.name.split('.').splice(-1)}`;
    return this.afsStorage.upload(`${folder}/${path.toLowerCase()}`, file).downloadURL();
  }

  removeFile(url: string): Observable<any> {
    const ref = this.afsStorage.storage.refFromURL(url);
    return Observable.fromPromise(ref.delete());
  }
}
```

The first method allows you to create a file, and returns an url. Once you get the url, you can create a document in your database to store it.

Comment: Still dont get it, if I leave only auth.uid it gives me same error, if I leave it with auth only , still the same.

Comment: Did you save new files in your firebase ? What is the reference of the files you're trying to get ?

Comment: And Yes I understood what you told, but that didn't really helped me to understand what happened with that error .

Comment: Yes I saved, it is Profile/UID/Upload/Filehere

Comment: No I mean, I need an URL :) not the complete one, just what is after the domain name.

Comment: this.uploadRef = this.db.list<any>(`uploads/${auth && auth.email && auth.uid}`);

Comment: Ok ... You know what an URL is ? For instance, one of my firebase files : `gs://firebase-url/posts/1519990215675-7pd9c0jw.jpg`

Comment: gs://adwoy-36a87.appspot.com/uploads/profilavatar.jpg

Comment: Thank you ! Now how do you expect your user to get this image when you use his ID as reference ? Unless the ID is `profilavatar.jpg` ... Also read **[the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files)** to get a grip on how file references work in firebase, and you will see how easy it is once you get it

Comment: The thing is that I upload a file (upload.ts) , and I have others like user.ts and profile.ts . As I understood , I cant upload upload.ts into profile.ts database. I need to link them both to one ?

Comment: You should use a service for that. Want to see how I created mine ?

Comment: I need and example for that, would be great. Because now I can see these photos if I use path uploads/ and in saveFileData "uploads/ . But if I add auth, cant.

Comment: and if You can look at all my upload.service : https://pastebin.com/YQ5kZTX3  ,this one works but there is no save to user uid so that only user would see that file.

Comment: I've posted an edit to my answer, I'm looking at your file now

Comment: If your issue is only about permissions, you should set them into your firebase console, not in your front-end !

Comment: It's a service as you saw. And everything works really fine. I can see all photos in uploads/ via front-end now. But It's not what I want, I want to upload them to my profile->uploads->file with auth.uid. That's where I can't make it.

Comment: I want users only to see their uploaded photos , not all so I need to change it.

Comment: Oooooooooooh that's not what I understood ! What you should do, is create a document for every picture you upload, with the user id in it. This way, you can use the firestore to request your images, which is way more powerful than relying on the picture URL.

Comment: Still hard to imagine how to change my code. As I understood now I need to save in firestore not in database?

Comment: No, you need to save it in your database, **then** in firestore. This way, your firestore document can have the url, the user id, the creation date (useful for sorting), and every other thing you would like to have.

Comment: So there is no way of doing it with my code in pastebin ?

Comment: There will always be a way, I'm just giving you the easiest one. If you don't want it that's fine by me, but unfortunately for you, that's the only one I know :/

Comment: I still think if I can upload information about file to my user->profile (As I did, but couldnt see these files) .  I can make it with my code but there is something that I dont see.